# Security of a Unity 2017 Cache Server

Tags: appsec, ports

I am currently running a cache server on an ubuntu machine on our local network for an upcoming game. We have several off-site members of our team who would like to make use of the cache server too.

It would be as easy as port forwarding to the static internal ip of our cache server machine, but the problem I have is that I'm uncertain if there's any major security concerns about just port forwarding to this machine and providing the external ip address of our office to our offsite members.

Could someone discover and download all of our unreleased game assets from the unity cache server? I see no form of authentication to make use of it, and no mention of security when publicly hosting a cache server either.

My question here is: what is the best way to safely expose a unity cache server box to the outside world while maintaining some degree of security. Is it reasonable to just port forward to this machine or are there known flaws with this simple strategy?

Comment: Why not have the remote users VPN into your network?

Comment: Hello @AstroDan we are working at a coworking space and do not own the router/network we are on. We managed to get ports forwarded to one of our computers running Ubuntu (I'm not very familiar with it), however. Do you have any good articles I could read to figure out how to set up a VPN for our external team to connect to? What do we need to do to set up and connect securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see no form of authentication to make use of it

I think in this case you have to wrap the process yourself. `stunnel` is an application that allows you to wrap any TCP connection with SSL and permits mutual authentication where both the client and server are validated.

You would run stunnel to forward connections to the localhost only listening service on the Unity server. Your developers would run stunnel clients to connect to your server and provide a port on the local machine and then connect to the Unity cache on the local machine port, thus forwarding all communication over an authenticated and encrypted channel.